# python database error (column not allowed here)

Tags: python, cx-oracle

**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here**

cur.execute(insert...) is showing the error of column not allowed here

```
import cx_Oracle

class Student:
    def __init__(self,studentname,studentperformance):

        connection = cx_Oracle.connect('saif/saif')
        cur = connection.cursor()

        cur.execute('create table student (studentrollno number(10),studentname varchar2(20),studenttype varchar2(20),studentperformance number(5,2),category varchar2(20),bookbank number(1))')

        self.rollno = 171641000
        self.studentname = studentname
        self.studentperformance = studentperformance
        # Line below is showing database error
        cur.execute('insert into student(studentrollno,studentname,studentperformance) values(self.rollno,self.studentname,self.studentperformance)')

s = Student("saif",75)
```

Comment: added the question

Comment: There still isn't a question, just an error.

Answer (score 1):

This line tries to use Python variables `self.rollno` etc in the SQL statement:

```
 cur.execute('insert into student(studentrollno,studentname,studentperformance) values(self.rollno,self.studentname,self.studentperformance)')
```

But because they are inside quotes the Python values are not substituted.  The string is sent verbatim to the database, which can't understand it.

To use bind variables a placeholder like `:bvid` below is used in the text for each variable, see some of the [examples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindQuery.py) e.g.:

```
sql = 'select * from SampleQueryTab where id = :bvid'

print("Query results with id = 4")
for row in cursor.execute(sql, bvid = 4):
    print(row)
print()
```